# Understanding PyTorch's Implementation of an RNN

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, implementation

I would like to refer to this paper by Schmidt, where RNNs are generally described: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.05911.pdf. So, according to Eq. (1) and (2) of the paper, we need three weight matrices W_hh, W_xh and W_ho. However, when printing the number of parameters for a simple RNN, I do not see the matrix W_ho, which I do not understand (the matrix W_xh is referred to as W_ih in the printout):

[image]

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`w_ho` would be the matrix from hidden to output. In your setup, that is most likely `fc.weight` and `fc.bias`. You can verify this also by checking the number of parameters or the dimension. You should check the dimension of matrices rather than the number of params to verify this.

Update: From the comments of OP, I understand that the OP had problems understanding the output of PyTorch's RNN module. So I am explaining that below.

An RNN update can be written (w/o bias and non-linearity) as:

```
h(t,l) = h(t-1,l)Whh(l) + h(t,l-1)Wxh(l)
```

where `t` denotes time and `l` denotes layer. `h(.,0)` i.e., at `l=0`, `h` is same as the input.

Now, the RNN module implements this and outputs the hidden states at the last layer, i.e., `h(t,L)` for all t and the last hidden state at each layer i.e., `h(N,1)` to `h(N,L)` (as `h_n`). It does not implement a fully connected output layer as mentioned in the paper linked above.

Why only these two outputs?

- A lot of problems that use RNN have output either the same size as the sequence (for example, POS tagging) or a single output (for example, classification). For the former, you are likely to use the last hidden state at each time and for the latter, you are likely to use the hidden state from the last layer (or all the layers maybe).
- Using only these outputs, it is possible to add more RNN layers (using the output) or continue processing the sequence (using the last hidden state).

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Unfortunately, ths is not correct, as `fc` referes to fully-connected layer, my apologies, I should have written it in the question.

Comment: Can you share the code/objective you are trying to achieve? I am suspecting that you might not have/need an output layer.

Comment: In other words, the pytorch or any other implementation of RNN does not add output layer. They only add connection from input and recurrent layer.

Comment: It's a simple classification problem with MNIST, nothing fancy. But that's weird, because according to the PyTorch docu, what the RNN returns is both the hidden state and an output: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.RNN.html

Comment: If you read carefully output is the hidden state at each step .. note the sentence `containing the output features (h_t) from the last layer of the RNN...` in the description of output.

Comment: You are right! But then, if the output already returns `the output features (h_t) from the last layer of the LSTM, for each t`. What does the `h_n` return then? I have troubles understanding the documentation, because it says `containing the final hidden state for each element in the batch`. But then, shouldn't this already be included in the output?

Comment: I have updated the answer. I hope it clarifies the confusion.